# how to retrieve first column value from array

Tags: php, opencart

I am new in programming.
i have added custom field in opencart history table shipping_method
if i update customer history multiple time it updates history very well
but here i want retrieve first value from `shipping_method` column

```
shipping_method

value1

value2

value3
```

Here i just want display value1 only not other values
I am using code this code to display

```
<?php foreach ($histories as $history) { ?>

<td class="text-left"><?php echo $history['shipping_type'];?></td>

<?php } ?>
```

But it displays all values from shipping_method column

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Well as you're question is hard to understand, I will give you a answer to what I believe the question is.

Try to select the first value of an array:

```
 echo $history['shipping_type'][0];
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but this is just showing first character

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you can `echo` the value of `$history['shipping_type']`, `$history['shipping_type']` is not an array or obj but a string.

So by these steps to output the first value1.

First: use `trim()` to remove the space of this string;

Second: get the content befroe first ' ', with `substr` and `strpos`. Here you also can convert the string to array with `explode()`.

```
$string = trim($history['shipping_type']);
echo substr($string, 0, strpos($string, ' '));
```

Comment: Thanks for your concerned here you can see in one table shipping_method is retrieve all the values in a column. But if you check above its again showing all column values i just want show first value (sm) only at above table not multiple values http://prntscr.com/dnod67